# Testing phonegap ajax locally in a browser?

Tags: ajax, html, cordova

Is there any product or tool I can use to test a phonegap application's ajax in chrome? I'd like to keep developing in Chrome, but cross-domain requests are going to kill me here.

Ideally, I could still use chrome, and somehow the ajax would get intercepted and run by a proxy of some sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start chrome using `--disable-web-security` and you can make cross-site ajax requests. This was broken for a while, but it's fixed again.

Answer (score 1):

use the simulator. If that doesn't suit your needs your best bet is to dev that portion elsewhere on the server, or create the proxy.

Comment: What simulator? ;) I build for iPhone and Android, and I use phonegap build to do the building. I don't touch an APK until I'm getting screenshots for a new deployment or update.

Comment: At first I downvoted you, but 'create the proxy' might actually work. If I detect Ext.is.Desktop, I can change the endpoint to a localhost url.

Comment: haha glad that saved myself from downvote to oblivion. Yeah I would say a proxy should work just fine.